# VideoJS does not add Range header to the Request

Tags: streaming, http-live-streaming, video.js

I'm trying to get VideoJS working with a m3u8 hls playlist using range requests, but for some reason dispite that other players are working fine, my VideoJS is always downloading the whole file. So I can Definitly confirm since other players are fine that my Playlist is setup fine and also my NGINX config, but I never see that VideoJS has a Range header at the requests its doing to my streaming backend.

This is how my Playlist is structured:

```
#EXT-X-VERSION:7
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE VOD


#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=281600,CODECS="mp4a.40.2"
a-aac-mp4a.40.2_256000/master.m3u8
```

The actual track playlist referenced by the playlist from above:

```
#EXT-X-VERSION:7
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="file.m4s",BYTERANGE="761@0"
#EXTINF:4.017052,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:129719@761
file.m4s
#EXTINF:3.993832,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:128476@130480
file.m4s
...
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

But as already mentioned, other players are working absolutly fine with this setup, but VideoJS does not include and Range in the Requests it sends to my NGINX. Why that?

Does sombody use VideoJS with byte range requests and can help me?